# Golang SSL TCP socket certificate configuration

Tags: ssl, tcp, go

I'm creating a Go TCP server (NOT http/s) and I'm trying to configure it to use SSL. I have a StartCom free SSL certificate which I am trying to use to accomplish this. My server code looks like this:

```
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("example.com.pem", "example.com.key")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading certificate. ",err)
    }
    trustCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("sub.class1.server.ca.pem")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading trust certificate. ",err)
    }
    validationCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ca.pem")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading validation certificate. ",err)
    }
    certs := x509.NewCertPool()
    if !certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(validationCert) {
        fmt.Println("Error installing validation certificate.")
    }
    if !certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(trustCert) {
        fmt.Println("Error installing trust certificate.")
    }

    sslConfig := tls.Config{RootCAs: certs,Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}

    service := ":5555"
    tcpAddr, error := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", service)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: Could not resolve address")
    } else {
        netListen, error := tls.Listen(tcpAddr.Network(), tcpAddr.String(), &sslConfig)
        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println(error)
        } else {
            defer netListen.Close()

            for {
                fmt.Println("Waiting for clients")
                connection, error := netListen.Accept()
```

I've tried switching around the order of the certs, not including some certs, etc. but the output from `openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect localhost:5555` remains essentially the same, `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`. See [here](http://pastebin.com/hALjVZb3) for full output. I seem to be doing something wrong with the intermediate certificates, but I have no idea what. I have been working on this for a few days, lots of googling and SO'ing, but nothing seemed to quite fit my situation. I have set up many certificates in Apache and HAProxy, but this really has me stumped.

Comment: Don't use `error` as your error value, since that masks the built-in interface name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RootCAs` field is for clients verifying server certificates. I assume you only want to present a cert for verification, so anything you need should be loaded into the `Certificates` slice.

Here is a minimal example:

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("example.com.pem", "example.com.key")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error loading certificate. ", err)
}

tlsCfg := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}

listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp4", "127.0.0.1:5555", tlsCfg)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer listener.Close()

for {
    log.Println("Waiting for clients")
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go handle(conn)
}
```

Even though you're not using HTTPS, it may still be useful to walk through the server setup starting at [`http.ListenAndServeTLS`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.ListenAndServeTLS).

Comment: Should the intermediate certificate be added into the example.com.pem file then? So it is loaded with the main certificate?

Comment: @kkhugs: I don't have a cert requiring an intermediate handy, but I'm fairly certain you should just chain them into your `example.com.pem`, like you would in nginx for example (docs say `Certificates contains one or more certificate chains`).

Comment: Thanks, adding the intermediate into the cert file and using as suggested worked perfectly!

Comment: @QuentinSkousen just to confirm, you first generate a local cert and key pair and then append the intermediate cert into the generated cert file; and it works? I am given a cert file from the security team but I thought it needs both a private key and a cert to start a https server in Go.

Comment: @dragonfly02 if you have been given a cert file, you wouldn't be generating anything locally. A locally generated cert file wouldn't be certified on the web, but of course you could use it to encrypt internal traffic.