# Intermediate certificate doesn't match private key with Go

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am trying to build a Go (golang) program that will run https application.

I am really having trouble with SSL intermediate certificate and don't know where the problem, is it from my certificate or from Go language application.

So, I have from my SSL CA providers two certificate files : the server certificate, and intermediate certificate.

So, I am trying to load these certificates from my go code like this:

```
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}
tlsConfig.Certificates = make([]tls.Certificate, 2)
var err error
tlsConfig.Certificates[0], err = tls.LoadX509KeyPair(serverCertificate, privateKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
tlsConfig.Certificates[1], err = tls.LoadX509KeyPair(intermeddiateCertificate, privateKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

server := &http.Server{
    ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    TLSConfig:      tlsConfig,
    Addr:           ":443,
}

   app.RunServer(server)
```

the code fails on the second load of certificate on this line

```
tls.LoadX509KeyPair(intermeddiateCertificate, privateKey)
```

The error is the certificate doesn't match the private key.

Does the intermediate certificate should match the private key in SSL/TLS world?

or it doesn't have to.
And in case doesn't have to, then how to load the certificate without a private key?

should I return back to my CA and tell them how come the intermediate certifcate doesn't match the private key?

Comment: As @Steffen answered, it will work if you concatenate the cert and intermediate cert files into a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a key for the intermediate certificate, only for the server certificate. Note that I don't know much about Go, but according to [Golang SSL TCP socket certificate configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898723/golang-ssl-tcp-socket-certificate-configuration) you simply include the intermediate certificate into the same PEM file as the server certificate.